# What does Mr. Lahey mean by "I am the liquor"?

Tags: analysis, trailer-park-boys

This is in reference to S5/ep9 *[I am the Liquor](http://trailerpark.wikia.com/wiki/I_Am_The_Liquor_(Episode))* in which Mr. Lahey, in response to Randy's question:

> RANDY: Mr. Lahey, is this you talking, or is it the liquor?  
>   LAHEY: Randy... [drinks]...  **I am the Liquor.**
>   
> <sub>SOURCE: Youtube ["I am the Liquor"](https://youtu.be/zWCBghizQUs)</sub>

What does Mr. Lahey mean by this?  Does it relate to the Dionysian cult practies and ideas?

([Bacchic revels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacchanalia) are an important part of life in Sunnyvale.  In other episodes, references are made to "let[ting] the liquor do the thinking" as a method of problem solving, and in Season 11, Mr. Lahey states that the liquor talks to him, providing instructions on actions he must take.  Where alcohol is usually regarded as dulling the mental faculties, on Trailer Park Boys it is often presented as a method of achieving clarity, an ironic inversion.  But spirits, in the sense of alcohol, are still utilized in religious ceremonies to this day.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also might be reference to **Salvador Dali**:

> I don't do drugs. I'm drugs.

Taken from an interview conducted by Paloma Chamorro in Madrid (Spain), 1982; as quoted in Salvador Dalí: *a la conquista de lo irracional*, Javier Pérez Andújar (2003) p. 245.

Answer (score 3):

Randy's question asks if Lahey truly intends what he's saying, or if he's just inebriated and speaking about thoughts that a sober person would have the sense to suppress. Lahey's response means that "the liquor" (being drunk or drinking) is an inseparable part of his identity, and implies that this is his true state of mind.

Bear in mind, an important part of Dunsworth's character is that Lahey will often go on drunken tirades that don't make any sense, such as when he mentions to Randy that people who don't know how to drink "drink against the grain of the liquor". This is a key element of the show's humour, and there aren't necessarily deeper meanings to his statements.

Comment: So in your opinion Lahey's statement does not indicate having become an avatar of Dionysus?  *(I tend to find TPB one of the most intelligent shows on television;)*

Comment: @DukeZhou Occam's razor.  It is much more likely that they were trying to make the obvious point that "Drunk Lahey" considers drunkenness to be his "normal" state.  This itself is a reoccurring theme of the show, where you basically have "Sober Lahey" as the friendly man who never wants to drink again; who always changes to "Drunk Lahey" and goes on similar drunken rampages.

Comment: @JMac absolutely, but I don't think that's all there is to it.  (See [okmanek's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/85153/40263))  A surprisingly high number of stoners I know have watched the Dali documentaries, and it's quite possible the Boys were referencing the Dali quote, which connotes avatarship.  This is a theme that's been heavily mined on the show, where the liquor "speaks" to Lahey, or Randy decides to "let the liquor do the thinkin'" as a method of problem solving re: Don/Donna.

Comment: @DukeZhou I really don't think a large part of that is implied.  I've never consciously heard that Dali quote; yet when that line came up in the show, it seemed like the obvious line to have him say "I am the liquor".  You really don't have to invoke outside sources to see that line as fully consistent with the themes, and not an external reference to anything at all.

Comment: @Jmac Also, Lahey is obviously one of the crazier characters, especially when drunk, but this type of divine madness goes back to [Bacchantes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maenad) (ecstatic followers of Dionysus) and the [Priestesses of Apollo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia) at Delphi, known as Mantises ([μάντις](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dma%2Fntis)), from which we derive the term "manic", connoting divine madness or inspiration, often linked with prophecy.

Comment: This degree of analysis may not have been consciously applied in creating the running gag, but it definitely applies!